# LINQ Query for getting count in ASP.Net MVC 5 Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

Need help in writing LINQ Query to get count of employee based on department.

**Department Model**

```
public class Department
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

**Employee Model**

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }
}
```

**MyViewModel**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
}
```

**LINQ Query**

```
    public ActionResult shows()
    {
        //one department can have many employees and one employee can only be parrt of one department
        // below LINQ query fetches the count of employees belonging to each department
        var x = _context.Employees.Include("Department").GroupBy(e => e.DepartmentId)
     .Select(y=> new MyViewModel{
             Department= y.Key, // ERROR HERE AS Cannot type cast string to integer
            count = y.Count()               
        }).ToList();
     // code removed for brevity
        return Content("x");
    }
```

**Output Expected**

```
Department                 Count (or employees)

Human Resource               10

Information Tech              5
```

**Question**
How to write a LINQ Query to get the output as above. Please guide me.

Comment: `Department= y.First().Department.Name,` (assumes `Department` contains a property named `Name`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I am really sorry, but I could not follow you. In this tutorial "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v1B3R-kb9CU&list=PL6n9fhu94yhVm6S8I2xd6nYz2ZORd7X2v&index=29" at 1:57 minute its working fine for the tutor.

Comment: Change `Department= y.Key` to `Department= y.First().Department.Name`

Comment: And that tutorial is using `GroupBy(e => e.Department.Name)` in which case you can use `Department= y.Key,`

Comment: I got error as `the "first" cannot be used a final query operation"`

Comment: `consider using method "firstordefault" in the instance instead`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149868/discussion-between-unbreakable-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options for modifying your query. I am assuming your `Department` model contains a property `string Name` which you want to assign to the `Department` property of your view model.

1. Get the first `Department` in the grouped collection and assign its
   `Name` property to your view models `Department` property. Note that
   you need to add `.ToList()` before `.GroupBy()` so that the
   first part of the query is executed before grouping

   ```
   var x = _context.Employees
       .Include("Department")
       .ToList()
       .GroupBy(e => e.DepartmentId)
       .Select(y => new MyViewModel
       {
            Department = y.First().Department.Name,
            count = y.Count()               
       }).ToList();
   ```
2. Change the `.GroupBy()` expression to group by the `Name` property
   of the `Department` property

   ```
   var x = _context.Employees
       .Include("Department")
       .GroupBy(e => e.Department.Name)
       .Select(y=> new MyViewModel
       {
           Department = y.Key,
           count = y.Count()               
       }).ToList();
   ```

Comment: Kindly do explain why even after grouping by ID (logically wrong) we still get the correct output.

Comment: Caution here grouping only by the name property of the department should work appropriately only if you have an unique constraint on the Name column ensuring you have unique department names. If you have duplicate department names for some reason you'll get the sum of employees in those lets say two departments. The best thing will be to group by Id AND Name,  see my answer.

Comment: @MihailShishkov: Makes perfect sense. I am just doing it for a learning purpose, but I will pay heed to what you are telling. Thanks a ton!. I will try your solution too. :)

Comment: @MihailShishkov, You answer is grouping by the Employees `DepartmentId` and Employees `Name` (not Department `Name`) which is not what OP wants

Comment: In option 1 you'll have to retrieve every employee from the database which is bad. What if there are thousands of employees? Effectively what you need @Unbreakable is this SQL to be executed on the server SELECT DepId, Name, COUNT(1) AS EmplCount FROM Employees GROUP BY DepId, Name

Comment: @MihailShishkov, I agree the first one is not as efficient (it was to answer the question directly) which is why I added the 2nd option (and it's only necessary to group by `Department.Name` - not by  `DepartmentId` as well)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I totally understood your first LINQ Query now and why it works.Silly me, now I realize that grouping by name is kind of same as grouping by ID (assuming both are unique). I gave some thought to your LINQ and now I know why it works fine. Thanks again. :)

Comment: So your first LINQ Query will find all the similar DepartmentId's present in the Employee Table and will group them accordingly. :)

Comment: My point was that this depends on the Department.Name to be unique

Answer (score 1):

```
public ActionResult shows()
    {
        //one department can have many employees and one employee can only be parrt of one department
        // below LINQ query fetches the count of employees belonging to each department
        var x = _context.Employees.Include("Department").GroupBy(e => new { e.DepartmentId, e.Department.Name})
     .Select(y=> new MyViewModel{
             Department= y.Key.Name
            count = y.Count()               
        }).ToList();
     // code removed for brevity
        return Content("x");
    }
```

the key here is to group by DepartmentId AND Name

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
public ActionResult shows()
{
    //one department can have many employees and one employee can only be parrt of one department
    // below LINQ query fetches the count of employees belonging to each department
    var x = _context.Employees.Include("Department").GroupBy(e => e.DepartmentId)
 .Select(y=> new MyViewModel{
         Department= y.Key.DepartmentName, // or whatever property you have for storing the name
        count = y.Count()               
    }).ToList();
 // code removed for brevity
    return Content("x");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code :

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MvcApplication1.Models;

namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
     
     public class HomeController : Controller
     {
          public ActionResult Index()
          {
               var dataContext = new MovieDataContext();
               int count = (from row in dataContext.Movies
                    where row.IsEnquiry == true
                 select row).Count();
               ViewBag.ItemCount = count;
               return View();
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Explain your answer